# How to change the up button icon in the action bar on Android?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I'd like to change the up button icon in the action bar on Android to display the navigation drawer menu icon. I'm trying this and it seems to work, but is it the right way to do it?

```
    private void configureToolbar() {

    if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.drawer_toolbar);
        mToolbar.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.navigation_drawer_title));
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    } else {
        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        mToolbar.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.officer_activity_title));
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.menu);
    }

    setDrawerToggle();

}
```

This is considering that the [android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html) is deprecated and the new [support.v7 class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html) doesn't allow you to pass the icon drawable into its constructor.

Answer (score 0):

impost android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle and use toolbar

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        if (toolbar != null) {
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        }

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,
                mDrawerLayout,
                toolbar,
                R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close){
                        @Override
                        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                            // code here will execute once the drawer is opened 
                            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                            // Code here will execute once drawer is closed
                            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        };
```

add below code in xml for toolbar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    />
```

Comment: Yes I do that. I just want to change the home icon on the toolbar from the arrow icon to the menu icon.